# ActionScript3 URLLoader doesnt load page or respond to Event.Complete

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I have a class http://pastie.org/5910058 (Full code https://gist.github.com/4656909 ) but when I call the `authorize` method, the `Event.COMPLETE` is never called.

Thank you.

Comment: I would try using a network monitor or debug proxy to see the result of the underlying request.  Could the response be incomplete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was sandbox limitation i guess, because locally I was able to URLLoad the google, and I dont know what I thought when I tried to access private api from client side, that way exposing key.

Answer (score 1):

Add an `HTTPStatusEvent.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS` handler to the loader and see what the `status` property is on the event. My guess is one of two things are happening: You are getting a non-200 status return (meaning the URL is bad in some way) or the download itself never finished.

Alternatively, you are reusing the loader each time. So if you call `authorize()` more than once, the previous loader is forgotten and it will never dispatch a COMPLETE event.

Comment: The site loads fine in browser and the authorize is called only once, but Ill try to check the HTTP status.

Comment: That seems to freeze the code, like no code executes after the HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS. Maybe its something doing with that I am using flashpunk engine? I havnt had such problem so far. https://gist.github.com/4656909

Comment: Nope doesnt seem that FlasPunk would cause any trouble. I have no idea why that doesnt work ):